# how to achieve jquery vertical magic line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[i need this border to be moved when an li element is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RyG.png)I am creating a movable border for the li element where I tried to implement the jquery-magicline-navigation as vertically using top but that moving border is getting the same top value for all the li elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subscriptions-life-cycle li div").on("click", function() {
    $("#subscriptions-life-cycle li.div.active-class").removeClass("active-class");
    $(this).addClass("active-class");
  });

  function slidingLine() {
    var $el, topPos, newHeight,
      $mainNav = $("#subscriptions-life-cycle");
    $mainNav.append("<li><div class='active-life-cycle'></div></li>");
    var $slidingLine = $(".active-life-cycle");

    $slidingLine // Defining initial height and position
      .height($(".active-class").innerHeight())
      .css("top", $(".active-class").position().top)
      .data("origTop", $slidingLine.position().top)
      .data("origHeight", $slidingLine.height());

    $("#subscriptions-life-cycle li div ").click(function() { // Set new height and position
      $el = $(this);
      topPos = $el.position().top;
      newHeight = $el.innerHeight();
      $slidingLine.stop().animate({
        top: topPos,
        height: newHeight
      });
    }, function() {
      $slidingLine.stop().animate({
        top: $(".active-class").position().top,
        height: $(".active-class").innerHeight()
      });
    });
  }

  slidingLine();
});
```

```css
.life-cycle-content-list {
  padding: 0% 10% 0 5%;
  list-style: square;
}

.life-cycle-content-list li {
  padding: 4%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.active-life-cycle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border: 0.5px solid;
}

ul#subscriptions-life-cycle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="life-cycle-content-list" id="subscriptions-life-cycle">
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle active-class" id="pricing-plan">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Pricing plan information
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Simplify signup process by providing multiple plans, addons, and coupons. Provide customers the freedom to try your offering with free trials.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="payment-process-life-cycle">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Payment process
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Collect online and offline payments via leading payment gateways. Make the checkout process a cinch with slick and secure hosted payment pages.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="billing-experience">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Billing experience
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Set your invoicing to auto-pilot but make sure that it still reflects your brand. Store customer card information securely for convenient billing.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="involuntary-churn">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Involuntary churn
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Don't let involuntary failed payments affect your rapport with customers. Automate card retries to Maximize your revenue.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="collaboration">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Collaboration
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Empower your customers by providing a self-service portal and strengthen your relationship with them by communicating about payment failures and card expirations.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[as you can see in image that border is not appiled properly and also it is just appended to li element but not moved to required position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvIzc.png)

Comment: I don't understand `but it didn't that slide-border` in your punctuation-less sentence

Comment: @JeremyThille now ?

Comment: Yes, better, thanks. I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from passing two functions to the `.click()` handler.

From [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/), `.click()` does accept two arguments, but the first argument (which is optional), if present, must be an object containing data that will be passed to the event handler. In your case, you're just passing two functions. `.click()` does not recognize this signature.

I'm not sure what the second argument (which is considered by jQuery as the actual event handler function) is for, I removed it, and now it works :

```js
var $el, topPos, newHeight,
  $mainNav = $("#subscriptions-life-cycle");

$mainNav.append("<li><div class='active-life-cycle'></div>");

var $slidingLine = $(".active-life-cycle"),
  $activeClass = $(".active-class")

$slidingLine // Defining initial height and position
  .height($activeClass.height())
  .width($activeClass.width())
  .css("top", $activeClass.position().top)
  .data("origTop", $slidingLine.position().top)
  .data("origHeight", $slidingLine.height());

$("#subscriptions-life-cycle .toggle-life-cycle")
  .click(function() { // Set new height and position
    console.log("click");
    $el = $(this);
    topPos = $el.position().top;
    newHeight = $el.innerHeight();

    $slidingLine.stop().animate({
      top: topPos,
      height: newHeight
    });

  });
```

```css
.life-cycle-content-list {
  padding: 0% 10% 0 5%;
  list-style: square;
}

.life-cycle-content-list li {
  padding: 4%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.active-life-cycle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border: 0.5px solid;
}

ul#subscriptions-life-cycle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="life-cycle-content-list" id="subscriptions-life-cycle">
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle active-class" id="pricing-plan">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Pricing plan information
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Simplify signup process by providing multiple plans, addons, and coupons. Provide customers the freedom to try your offering with free trials.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="payment-process-life-cycle">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Payment process
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Collect online and offline payments via leading payment gateways. Make the checkout process a cinch with slick and secure hosted payment pages.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="billing-experience">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Billing experience
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Set your invoicing to auto-pilot but make sure that it still reflects your brand. Store customer card information securely for convenient billing.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="involuntary-churn">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Involuntary churn
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Don't let involuntary failed payments affect your rapport with customers. Automate card retries to Maximize your revenue.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="toggle-life-cycle" id="collaboration">
      <div class="life-cycle-content-sub-header">
        Collaboration
      </div>
      <div class="life-cycle-content-desc">
        Empower your customers by providing a self-service portal and strengthen your relationship with them by communicating about payment failures and card expirations.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: as we need to use position: absolute for moving ,  only  border (border-left) is visible where else i need to cover the whole content using border is  there any other way to overcome ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `only border is visible where else i need to cover the whole content` ?

Comment: look at the first image attached at the top, the border covers the whole content of li element @Jeremy Thille

Comment: is their any way?

Comment: ... well yeah, the "line" is actually a div without width. Just give it a width (I have updated my answer)

Comment: getting the same value for top position 21 and i am having few more click event listeners in my page @Jeremy Thille

Comment: and also there is an extra li element with bullet is append at the last need to be removed when the top position is changed.

Comment: This is a different problem and a different question. I believe I have answered your original question, haven't I?

Comment: sorry, I had that code already and u just gave me to fix width but my original question is to make it movable, you still weren't able to full fill it.

Comment: Run my snippet. Each paragraph is clickable, and the "magic line" which is now a full rectangle, moves where you click.

Comment: yes I did but it is not working in real time and also see that your li element with the bullet style remains same even after moving it and also I am having 2-3 functions in the page where they all are event click listeners, what you just did is you made a full rectangle with setting width that's good, but my core part of the questions is still remains unanswered.

Comment: Look, I'm having a really hard time understanding your sentences and your questions. What do you mean "in real time" ?? You asked for the line to move to the clicked paragraph, which it does, and to have a width, which it has. Now you want some "real time" stuff, change some style somewhere, etc. I did what I could to understand your monolithic writing, sorry if I failed.

Comment: no need to regret u did it better but still, the top value for the li element appended is not changing that why I can't agree your answer and also refer: https://codepen.io/LouVerdun/pen/aNdBaz?editors=1010